# Airflow Docker Deployment: Task Not Getting Run After start_date + schedule_interval

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, airflow

I am new to Airflow.  I think I have read all of the articles in the Airflow documentation about scheduling, but I still cannot seem to get my DAGs running after the start_date+schedule_interval (i.e. no task instances).  I am using docker.  I am wondering it I am missing a command that is scheduling Dags, even though this wasn't the case when I was using the tutorial code.

Here is my dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev apt-utils build-essential
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Installs these and a few others
# mysqlclient==1.3.10
# airflow==1.7.1.3
COPY dependencies /dependencies
RUN pip install -r dependencies/requirements_loader.txt

COPY airflow /root/airflow

# Load other dependencies 


# I have tried many different variation of these commands with no luck
CMD airflow webserver -p 8080
CMD airflow scheduler -d DAG_id
```

I am using the PythonOperator with a module that loads a library that I wrote.  I am not sure if this is the right way for this, but it works `airflow test dag_id execution_date`.  This is what is most peculiar to me. The test works, but it never actually gets run when I start airflow.  I am using the LocalExecutor. here is my dag.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from my_lib import my_func

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 3, 6),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}


dag = DAG('dag_id', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="31 2 * * *")

t1 = PythonOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='run_my_func',
    provide_context=False,
    python_callable=my_func)
```

I have also messed around with the schedule interval and start date, including dates that started a month ago with a `@daily` interval.  None of these have given my any luck.

**What is really perplexing is that when I test a dag it works, but it is not getting scheduled and creating any task_instances after it is deployed.**

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a deployment that does properly schedule the dags? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: In your web ui have you turned your dag on? For example look in this image https://i.imgur.com/GkvqvLb.png. The dag is toggled on.

Comment: Just FYI, I found many inconsistencies in Airflow activation logic. It doesn't work the way most of us would assume. You need to dig through the code to understand why something doesn't start.  The concept of Airflow is great but the current implementation is very weird IMHO.

Comment: @nehiljain I actually do not see a place where I can turn on the dags.  http://imgur.com/a/tSwOi  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot use two CMD commands at the end of a dockerfile.  Once I created two dockerfiles with docker-compose, it worked fine.

> There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd